# how to pass list to function call from within another function

Tags: bash

I have two functions and im trying to figure out how to pass a list to a function call from within another function

```
func1{
files=()

$(func2 ${files[@]})
}

func2{
#do something with the list
}
```

Comment: Technically, you cannot pass the array as a single argument; you can only expand the array and pass each element as a separate argument.

Comment: For example, you couldn't do `func2 "${files1[@]}" "${files2[@]}"` and have `func2` know where the arguments from `files1` end and the arguments from `files2` begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have quotes (`"`) around your list when you do the call to preserve any spaces that might be in the individual strings in the list.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function func1 {
    files=("foo bar" "hello world")

    func2 "${files[@]}"
}

function func2 {
    for var in "$@"; do
        echo ">$var<"
    done
}

func1
```

Output:

```
>foo bar<
>hello world<
```